# Error while connecting to MySQL: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3310' (111 Connection refused) when using colab, works fine VSCODE

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I was using VS Code to work with my code, but when I'm using colab it is unable to connect to mysql and it was connecting and executing well with VS Code.

```
def process_row():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="", database="assignment1", port="3310")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        query = "SELECT * FROM temp_card_new;"
        cursor.execute(query)

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.close()

        return rows

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Error while connecting to MySQL:", error)
        return []
```

> ERROR: Error while connecting to MySQL: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3310' (111 Connection refused)

I've tried every possible thing, I'm unable to understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab does not run in your machine but on google servers. When you try to connect to the 127.0.0.1 aka "localhost", your code tries to connectto the mysql running *on the same server as the colab code is executed" and because its not on that machine, it fails.